# Getting checked rows from Telerik Kendo Grid in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a Telerik Kendo Grid with a checked column:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RunSummary>()
          .Name("CheckedPatients")
          .ToolBar(toolBar => 
                    toolBar.Custom()
                        .Text("Export To PDF")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
                        .Url(Url.Action("Export", "PatientReport", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" })))

          .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                .Ajax().PageSize(25)        
                .Sort(sort => sort.Add("UniqueId").Ascending())                        
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetRunSummaries", "PatientReport")))
          .Columns(columns =>
              {

                  columns.Bound(c => c.UniqueId).Title(ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Home.HomeStrings.UniqueId)
                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' unlock='true' class='primaryBox' id='#= UniqueId #' />");
                  columns.Bound(c => c.RunNo).Title(SharedStrings.Run);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Birthdate).Title(SharedStrings.Birthdate).Format("{0:g}").Filterable(true);

                  //columns.Bound(c => c.Age).Title(SharedStrings.Age).ClientTemplate("#= formatAge(Age)#");
                  columns.Bound(c => c.TimeOn).Title(PatientStrings.TimeOn)
                      .Format("{0:g}")
                      .Filterable(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.TimeOff).Title(PatientStrings.TimeOff)
                      .Format("{0:g}")
                      .Filterable(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.DischargedAlive).Title(SharedStrings.Age).Filterable(true);
              }
          )
          .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] {10, 25, 50, 100}))
          .Sortable()
          .Filterable( )
          .Events( e => e.FilterMenuInit("FilterMenuFunc") ) // apply x [closing box] on pop up filter box
          )
```

I have to get checked rows in an action of the controller. Please help how to do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: You checkboxes do not even have `name` and `value` attributes so nothing will be submitted to your controller

Comment: Are you worried about persistent checkboxes while paging? Or just the current checks on the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. At first, collect all checked boxes to an array:

```
$(document).on('change', '.primaryBox:checkbox', function (e) {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (isChecked) {
            checkedArray.push($(this).val());
        } else {
            checkedArray.remove($(this).val());

        }
    });
```

Then, send the array to the controller using Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/PatientReport/ExportToPDFStoredProcedures",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: { uniqueIds: checkedArray },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                     //do something
                                   } 
           else {
                    //do something else;
                }
...and finally in the controller make an action that has uniqueIds as argument:
public ActionResult ExportToPDF(List<String> uniqueIds)
        {  
//do something with UniqueIds
}
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

what I understand from your question is, you are trying to check checkbox from controller. For which you must have an indicator and set its value in controller and pass through model and bound it with the column in which checkbox are.
now use this

.ClientTemplate("<
input type='checkbox' #= indicator?checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx'  id='#= UniqueId #'
/>")

here indicator is that which you will bound with your column. if it is set checkbox will be checked else unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the current page of the grid.

```
            var checkedItems= [];
            $(".cbGridRow").each(function () {
                var cbRow = $(this);
                if (cbRow.is(':checked'))
                    checkedItems.push(this.id.substring(2));
            });
```

However, if your grid is set to Pageable then you will have to save and load selection in between page transitions. The easiest way to do this is to tie into the before and after page functions and maintain an array of unique ID's.

Or bind to the change event and read each checked item into a persistent array.